# npm start error with create-react-app with an Error Called -ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs

I am learning a ReactJs course and while creating FirstReactApp using commands in window-7.

```
npm install -g create-react-app 
npm create-react-app
```

Both of this code works fine but when i am trying to start the server using npm start then i am getting an error called

> ELiFECYLE

Below are the errors i am getting.

```
C:\my-react-app>npm start

> my-react-app@0.1.0 start C:\my-react-app
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^enter code here

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm- ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and after banging my head for a while I figured out the problem.
It is a very easy fix.

**You just need to change the version of your react-scripts to `2.1.8` in your project's package.json file.**

If you don't understand then Follow these baby steps :P .

## 1 Open the file package.json

This file is just inside your project folder. If you are using an editor like VSCode then you can use it to see this file.

## 2 Change react-scripts version

Inside package.json you will see dependencies block.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
```

Right now we have the latest version which is `3.0.0`. And I guess this is the real culprit here.

Change it to `2.1.8`.  See the image snap of my project.

[image]

## 3 Run npm install again and try npm start

Now it will work. I don't know why the version 3.0.0 is causing issue. But at this moment I think there is some bug, or may be anything else that I don't know yet.

May be the issue is something else, and something more specific. But so far I figured out this only.

Hope this helps you. Thank You :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem a few days ago. Try to run these commands

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Comment: firstly run  npm install react-scripts@2.1.8   "then"  npm start

Answer (score 0):

You should install node modules before starting your app. Run `npm install` or `npm i` and try again.

Comment: First  i have installed node modules using. using -> npm install -g create-react-app   -> Then created Project Folder Name using -> npx create-react-app  my-app....Now everything is working fine means Nodule Modules created inside my-app folder........Then start the server using.... ->  c:/ my-app> npm start...........but in this last step i am getting an error.

Comment: @AsifAhmad try `npm cache clean --force` and then create new one with `npx create-react-app xyz`

Comment: @NikitaIskorkin......I have applied your given command. still showing the Same Error....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly uninstall the existing npm package:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app (-g if you installed globally)
```

Secondly:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Again do this:

```
npm install -g create-react-app@latest and create-react-app my-app
```