# Error on npm start in npx create-react-app in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to react and when i create a react app via command

npx create-react-app my-app

The app created successfully but when i go to the directory and type command

npm start it gives me an error. There is a screenshot about it and i am using

node version 10.15.3 and 
npm version 6.4.1

````
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-first-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-first-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-24T08_20_34_606Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Check out here [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854680/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app-with-an-error-called-elifecycle/55854833)

Comment: +1 to @NicanorKorir. Also, this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985)